# How to pronounce possession of "coach's umbrella"?

Tags: pronunciation

> coach /koʊtʃ/
>
> umbrella /ʌmˈbrelə/

But how to pronounce "**coach's umbrella**"

[This page](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine) said "**The rules for the pronunciation of a noun with ’s are the same as the rules for pronunciation of plural forms of nouns.**"

So, Is `/koʊtʃɪzʌmˈbrelə/` correct?

If it is correct, then "**coach's umbrella**" & "**coaches' umbrella**" sound the same.

Comment: That looks good to me - sounds like *coaches umbrella*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, that's exactly how you pronounce it.

Comment: But it could be "coaches' umbrella"

Comment: @Tom Yep.  You can use context to figure out which one it is.